# Response is not getting logged?

Tags: tomcat, spring-ws

Hi 
I am using tomcat + spring 3.0 ws trying to log request and response
can see request in catalina, but no reponse??

```
     <bean id="soapLoggingInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor">
            <property name="logRequest" value="true" />
            <property name="logResponse" value="true" />
            <property name="logFault" value="true" ></property>

        </bean>


    <bean id="payloadMapping"
            class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
                    <property name="interceptors">
                <list>

                    <ref local="soapLoggingInterceptor" />

                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

<logger name="com.test.apptest">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
```

Comment: can you clarify that please example? see above added few more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding the following to my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, console
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
```

Of course the issue with this solution is it prints out all message going into and out of the services.

If you still want to use the logging interceptor then I think your logged above should read :

```
<logger name="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: The logging interceptor worked for me. One note - Within the logger node, I needed to add an appender-ref value to let it know which appender to write to. I pasted mine below (my appender name is "R"): 
    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor">
     <level value="DEBUG"/>
     <appender-ref ref="R"/>
 </logger>

Answer (score 0):

`SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` will only log at `DEBUG` level. So check your Tomcat logging config, and make sure that DEBUG-level logging is enabled for `org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor`

Comment: This has been done as well i can get request logs not response?? more code above